# How to not round values for a division with variables in SAS

Tags: sas, dataset, rounding, sas-macro

I have two numeric variables in `SAS`:

```
%let var1=10;
%let var2=8;
```

I have to do the division between the two, but if I do:

```
%let var3=%eval(&var2/&var1);
%put &var3;
```

the result is `0`. Because `var2` is a subset of `var1` and by default the system rounds the number to `0`. In fact if I do `&var1/&var2` the result is `1`.

Given that I have to use this value for a percent I have the need that it is maintained with the decimal.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Why do you want to divide something in the macro language??

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `%SYSEVALF()` if you want something other than integer arithmetic.

Macro code is for generating text.  If you really need to do calculations you should do it in a data step.

Comment: The second sentence in particular.  This isn't the right place to do this.